# Erase a texture on overlay bitmap - Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, paint, transparent

I have a `ImageView` that contains two bitmaps a background and a pattern painted on the foreground. What I want to do is erase the pattern painted on the foreground so that the full background is revealed on the erased parts. The erasing part I have figured out and this works.

My problem is that when I erase the touch position is inaccurate. This is because the `Bitmap` on the foreground's canvas isn't the same size as the `ImageView`'s canvas. I resize my `ImageView` in the `onMeasure` method to fit the screen without scaling it down.

How do I resolve this problem? I thought about using two image views, one for each bitmap, but this process is tedious and also causes performance issues. I would like to use one `ImageView` and two bitmaps.

Here is my code to explain my problem a bit more.

```
      final Paint pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
      pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT)); 
      pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
      pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, Blur.NORMAL));

      final Canvas c2 = new Canvas(_currentTextureBitmap);

      ImageView iv = new ImageView(this) {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int _width;
            int _height;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

                switch (ev.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { 

                    x = (int) ev.getX();
                    y = (int) ev.getY();

                    invalidate();

                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                    x = (int) ev.getX();
                    y = (int) ev.getY();

                    invalidate();
                    break;

                }    

                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override 
            protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
                Drawable d = getDrawable();

                if(d!=null){
                    // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
                    _width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                    _height = (int) Math.ceil((float) _width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
                    setMeasuredDimension(_width, _height);
                }else{
                    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
                super.onDraw(canvas);

                if (_selectedImageURI != null)
                    if (_erase) {
                        //draw background
                        canvas.drawBitmap(_backgroundBitmap, null, new RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), null);

                        if (_currentTextureBitmap != null) {
                            c2.drawCircle(x, y, 40, pTouch);
                            canvas.drawBitmap(_currentTextureBitmap, null, new RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), null);
                        }
                    }
               }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very simple solution. Just used the width of the biggest canvas, divided it by the smaller canvas, used that float value and multiplied it with the x and y value that was set on touch. This gave the correct coordinates to erase on the bigger canvas.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (_erase) {
        //draw background
        canvas.drawBitmap(_originalBitmap, null, new RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), null);

        if (_overlay != null) { 
            float x = (_x * ((float)_overlay.getWidth()/_width));
            float y = (_y * ((float)_overlay.getHeight()/_height));

            _canvasOverlay.drawCircle(x, y, 40, _touch);
            canvas.drawBitmap(_overlay, null, new RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), null);
        }
    }
}
```